# How do I compute the matrix gradient with respect to a submatrix by applying the chain rule?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2a \times 2a}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{b \times a}$ and $M \in \mathbb{R}^{a \times b}$, for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_{[0,\infty)}$. Define $$Y(X)=\begin{bmatrix}I_a&0_{a \times a}\\MX&I_a\end{bmatrix}\,.$$How do I compute the expression of the gradient $$\nabla_Xf\left(Y(X)\right)$$
in terms of $\nabla_Yf(Y)$? In other words, how can I apply the chain rule in this specific case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use $\{E_1, E_2\}$ to denote block matrix analogs of the standard basis vectors $\{e_1, e_2\}$
$$\eqalign{
E_1 &= \begin{bmatrix}I_a\\0\end{bmatrix},\,\,\,
E_2 &= \begin{bmatrix}0\\I_a\end{bmatrix} \cr
}$$
Then the matrix of interest can be written as
$$\eqalign{
Y &= E_1I_aE_1^T + E_2I_aE_2^T + E_2MXE_1^T \cr
dY &= E_2M\,dX\,E_1^T \cr
}$$
Assume that the gradient of $f$ wrt $Y$ is known to be $G=\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}$.

We can use this to write the differential of $f$ and then find its gradient wrt $X$ 
$$\eqalign{
df
 &= G:dY \cr
 &= G:E_2M\,dX\,E_1^T \cr
 &= M^TE_2^TGE_1:dX \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= M^TE_2^TGE_1 \cr
}$$
where a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
There are lots of rules for rearranging the terms in a Frobenius product which follow from the cyclic properties of the trace.

For example, all of the following are equivalent
$$\eqalign{
A:BC
 &= BC:A \cr
 &= A^T:(BC)^T \cr
 &= AC^T:B \cr
 &= B^TA:C \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks. To clarify though, f() is a scalar function, so we are asking for the gradient of a scalar function with respect to a matrix, which should still be a matrix. Why do we need the gradient of a matrix with respect to a matrix?

Comment: Also, the domain of $f$ is the space of matrices of dimension $2a \times 2a$, not the real line as implied by the fact that you use $f(1)$.

Comment: @pulosky Sorry, I completely misunderstood the question; thought you were doing something more complicated. The answer has been updated.